# Flex: Parse error: '<s:Button>' is not allowed to follow '</s:Button>'

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

The subject says it all. My simplified code is below:

```
<mx:DataGrid id="gridFields" width="100%">
  <mx:columns>
    <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="name" 
                       headerText="Name" />

    <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="description"
                       headerText="Description"/>

    <mx:DataGridColumn>
      <mx:itemRenderer>
        <fx:Component>
            <!--these two buttons are the problem-->
            <s:Button id="btnDeleteField"
                          label="Delete" 
                          click="outerDocument.deleteField(event)" />
            <s:Button id="btnEditField"
                      label="Edit"
                      click="outerDocument.editField(event)" />
        </fx:Component>
      </mx:itemRenderer>
    </mx:DataGridColumn>
  </mx:columns>
</mx:DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved my problem by doing the following

```
<mx:DataGridColumn>
  <mx:itemRenderer>
    <fx:Component>
      <s:MXDataGridItemRenderer>
        <s:HGroup>
          <mx:Button label="Aaa"/>  
          <mx:Button label="Bbb" />
        </s:HGroup>
      </s:MXDataGridItemRenderer>
    </fx:Component>
  </mx:itemRenderer>
</mx:DataGridColumn>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for posting this!  I was having a weird error 2025 on redraw involving a `VBox` as the top level component inside a `Component`, and miraculously wrapping it in an `MXDataGridItemRenderer` fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

You can only place one primary component inside an `<fx:Component> ... </fx:Component>` block, since you are technically extending (in the OOP sense) whatever class you use.  What you did is *loosely* the equivalent of writing `MyComponent extends Button extends Button` in ActionScript.

Instead, try placing the two buttons inside a single container, eg. a `Group` or `BorderContainer`.

Comment: I tried surrounding the two buttons with HGroup. It now compiles and runs, but throws this error while trying to render
TypeError: Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert metadata::MetadataTypesDialog2InnerClass0@16b96c29 to mx.controls.listClasses.IListItemRenderer.